# Implementing Applicative's (<*>) for Monad

Tags: haskell

`Applicative`'s has the `(<*>)` function:

```
(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#error) shows the following function.

Given:

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b  
ap f m = do
  g <- f        -- '<-' extracts f's (a -> b) from m (a -> b)
  m2 <- m       -- '<-' extracts a from m a 
  return (g m2) -- g m2 has type `b` and return makes it a Monad
```

How could `ap` be written with `bind` alone, i.e. `>>=`?

I'm not sure how to extract the `(a -> b)` from `m (a -> b)`. Perhaps once I understand how `<-` works in `do notation`, I'll understand the answer to my above question.

Comment: There are quite a few questions on SO about desugaring do-notation that might help you.  I think my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229518/how-to-write-without-do-notation/7229732#7229732) is good obviously, but there are others too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How could ap be written with bind alone, i.e. >>= ?

This is one sample implementation I can come up with:

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap xs a = xs >>= (\f -> liftM f a)
```

Of if you don't want to even use `liftM` then:

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf ma = mf >>= (\f -> ma >>= (\a' -> return $ f a'))
```

---

Intially these are the types:

```
mf  :: m (a -> b)
ma  :: m a
```

Now, when you apply bind (`>>=`) operator to `mf`: `mf >>= (\f-> ...`, then `f` has the type of:

```
f :: (a -> b)
```

In the next step, `ma` is also applied with `>>=`: `ma >>= (\a'-> ...`, here `a'` has the type of:

```
a' :: a
```

So, now when you apply `f a'`, you get the type `b` from that because:

```
f    :: (a -> b)
a'   :: a
f a' :: b
```

And you apply `return` over `f a'` which will wrap it with the monadic layer and hence the final type you get will be:

```
return (f a') :: m b
```

And hence everything typechecks.

Comment: could you please explain how `\f -> a >>= \a' -> return $ f a'` has a type of `a -> m b`? I'm not understanding `f`'s type & how you're applying it to `a'`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I have change the variables name to avoid confusion and have added explanation. Let me know if something confuses you.

Comment: Why are you using `~` instead of `::`?